# split and seperate based on specific values - jQuery

Tags: jquery, split

Basically my string looks like this.

```
568|896|2015-12-14 13:43:05||1|6666698|text1|999969|624|0|1|0|1^696|982|2015-11-14 13:43:05||2|6666695|text2|899969|634|0|0|0|0^147|111|2015-10-14 13:43:05||3|6666694|text3|799969|644|0|0|0|0^025|558|2014-09-14 13:43:05||4|6666693|text4|699969|654|0|1|0|1^925|777|2014-08-14 13:43:05||5|6666692|text5|599969|664|0|1|0|1^
```

Then i am spliting this string by `^` character

```
var allvalues = $('#allvalues').val();
var spval = allvalues.split('^');

console.log(spval[0])+"<br>";
console.log(spval[1])+"<br>";
console.log(spval[2])+"<br>";
console.log(spval[3])+"<br>";
console.log(spval[4])+"<br>";
```

Now this will give

```
568|896|2015-12-14 13:43:05||1|6666698|text1|999969|624|0|1|0|1
696|982|2015-11-14 13:43:05||2|6666695|text2|899969|634|0|0|0|0
147|111|2015-10-14 13:43:05||3|6666694|text3|799969|644|0|0|0|0
025|558|2014-09-14 13:43:05||4|6666693|text4|699969|654|0|1|0|1
925|777|2014-08-14 13:43:05||5|6666692|text5|599969|664|0|1|0|1
```

Now here i want to check each array after the split. And want to seperate the array based on last 4 numbers, in which all 4 numbers should be **0** `[0|0|0|0]`, within the array which are seperated by `|` pipe characters.

After the seperate i should get

```
696|982|2015-11-14 13:43:05||2|6666695|text2|899969|634|0|0|0|0
147|111|2015-10-14 13:43:05||3|6666694|text3|799969|644|0|0|0|0
```

AND

```
568|896|2015-12-14 13:43:05||1|6666698|text1|999969|624|0|1|0|1
025|558|2014-09-14 13:43:05||4|6666693|text4|699969|654|0|1|0|1
925|777|2014-08-14 13:43:05||5|6666692|text5|599969|664|0|1|0|1
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to get a new array with only the items ending in `0|0|0|0` or do you want to sort the items by their ending or group the items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate and put the values in two seperate arrays

```
var allvalues = $('#allvalues').val();
var spval     = allvalues.split('^');
var arr2      = [];
var arr1      = spval.filter(function(item) {
    if (item.trim().length === 0) return false;
    if (item.split('|').join('').slice(-4) === "0000") {
        arr2.push(item);
        return false
    }
    return true;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/oxuj2o8q/1/)

Comment: Thank you. But I couldn't follow this line `if (item.trim().length === 0) return false;`

Comment: You have a `^` at the end of the string, meaning you'll get one empy index when splitting. That line just remove any indices in the array that have an empty string as a value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
        var test = "568|896|2015-12-14 13:43:05||1|6666698|text1|999969|624|0|1|0|1^696|982|2015-11-14 13:43:05||2|6666695|text2|899969|634|0|0|0|0^147|111|2015-10-14 13:43:05||3|6666694|text3|799969|644|0|0|0|0^025|558|2014-09-14 13:43:05||4|6666693|text4|699969|654|0|1|0|1^925|777|2014-08-14 13:43:05||5|6666692|text5|599969|664|0|1|0|1^";
    var spval = test.split('^');
    var arr1 = new Array();
    var arr2 = new Array();
    $.each(spval,function(key,value){
        if( value.length >= 4 )
        {
            var lastFour = value.substring(value.length-8,value.length);
            if(lastFour == "|0|0|0|0")
            {
                arr1.push(value);
            }
            else
            {
                arr2.push(value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            arr2.push(value);
        }
    });

    alert(JSON.stringify(arr1));
    alert(JSON.stringify(arr2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var str = '568|896|2015-12-14 13:43:05||1|6666698|text1|999969|624|0|1|0|1^696|982|2015-11-14 13:43:05||2|6666695|text2|899969|634|0|0|0|0^147|111|2015-10-14 13:43:05||3|6666694|text3|799969|644|0|0|0|0^025|558|2014-09-14 13:43:05||4|6666693|text4|699969|654|0|1|0|1^925|777|2014-08-14 13:43:05||5|6666692|text5|599969|664|0|1|0|1^'

var _arr = str.split("^")

var _outArr1 = [];
var _outArr2 = [];
for(var i=0;i<_arr.length;i++) {
    if(_arr[i].match(/0\|0\|0\|0$/) != null) {
        _outArr1.push(_arr[i])
    } else {
        _outArr2.push(_arr[i])
    }
}
```